# Invalid Developer Key

Tags: youtube-api

I was reaching the youtube api quota limit while building my application so I added a developer key to the request and now I get a 403 error: Invalid Developer Key.

I've tried recreating my project and api key multiple times without any luck. I've tried adding the key to the URI as well as sending it in a header:

```
$c1 = curl_init($feedURL);
curl_setopt($c1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   'X-GData-Key: key=AIzaS...',
   'GData-Version: 2'
));
```

My application is simple, all requested data is public, so I don't see a reason to use the Zend PHP Client.

Comment: No ideas based on what you describe, since that sounds like it should work. Your full developer key isn't particularly sensitive information so feel free to post it here, or contact me directly with it, and I'll do some internal debugging t see what might be wrong with it.

Comment: AIzaSyCvQnREdHf4W7uEwQQ20AR0jPwrZajUYQU

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using a v3 "API key" while querying v2 of the API.

v3 "API key"s are obtained from the Access tab of https://code.google.com/apis/console/ and are what you use to make non-authenticated requests to any of the APIs listed on that console.

v2 "developer key"s are obtained from http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/ and is what you're looking for.

I believe that one of the goals is to retrofit v2 of the API to start supporting "API key"s from the API console, but that isn't something that's possible at this time.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! It would be really helpful to have all the api info in one place - I'm sure it will happen eventually.

Comment: Sorry to bump this old one. Link for the v2 api doesn't seem to work anymore, i'm redirected to a login page that keeps refreshing itself even when correct credentials are input. Did google introduce any breaking change about api v2?

Comment: Yes, v2 was deprecated and no longer works: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol