# Where did the v2 api key console go?

Tags: youtube-api

There used to be a YouTube api console for v2 that allowed generation of v2 api keys.  Mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293541/invalid-developer-key) by Jeff Posnick. I get a 404 error now.

I know that v2 has been deprecated but it takes time to switch to the new v3 version and we should be still be able to use v2 until the end date of April 2015.  Does anyone know where to get v2 api keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of the post you reference, Jeff mentioned that one goal is to make the old v2 API aware of new keys generated via the API console (now the cloud console). I just tested it and it seems to work now to use a "key for browser applications" for deprecated v2 calls as well as the read-only v3 API calls, but someone else may be able to comment if this is, in fact, accurate.